# How do I talk to Proventus about buying Breezehome?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to buy Breezehome but when I talk to Proventus (the guy who sells it to you),
he doesn't say anything about Breezehome.

Answer (score 3):

what you have to do is become the thane of whiterun so keep doing the story missions until you have to go to see the grey beards and when you talk to the jarl then he will make you the thane and you can then talk to proventus about breezehome.

Answer (score 1):

You must first retrieve the tablet from Bleak Falls Barrow. Then, Proventus should give you the option to buy Breezehome for 5000 gold, and furniture for extra money.
P.S.
To get the house for free, push Proventus toward the cabinet on the left side of the room. As soon as you ask to buy the house, put all of your money into it. It will be yours for no cost.